# getting error when using controller in fxml file JAVA Code

Tags: java, eclipse

Why does this error happen?

Here is the code :

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screen.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Hhlee.java**

```
public class Hhlee implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location , ResourceBundle resources) {
        btn1.setOnAction(event -> handleBtn1Action(event));
        btn2.setOnAction(event -> handleBtn2Action(event));
        btn2.setOnAction(event -> handleBtn3Action(event));
    }
    
    public void handleBtn1Action(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("버튼1 클릭");
    }
    
    public void handleBtn2Action(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("버튼2 클릭");
    }
    
    public void handleBtn3Action(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("버튼3 클릭");
    }
}
```

**Screen.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
        prefWidth="300.0" hgap="10.0" vgap="10.0"
        fx:controller="application.Hhlee"
        prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0" alignment="CENTER" spacing="20.0">
    <Button fx:id="btn1" text="버튼1"/>
    <Button fx:id="btn2" text="버튼2"/>
    <Button fx:id="btn3" text="버튼3"/>
</HBox>
```

Fist, i think that `fx:controller="PackageName.ClassName"`
Examine a Screen.fxml many times, But all of that Okay.

Second, Examine a fxml Path:

[image: Package Explorer]

Scribe error code below

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing a similar issue, and similar to what @0009laH has said, I put all the files `Main.java` , `Hhlee.java` , `Screen.fxml` in one package, that is in the `App/src/application`. That way, you won't have to specify the relative path every time, and you can just directly use this:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Screen.fxml"));
         Parent root=(Parent) loader.load();
         Scene scene = new Scene(root);
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help. i am appricaite your answer

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke an FXML file via `getClass().getRessource(path)`, you must provide a relative path starting from the location of your current class.

I would recommend you:

1. To put **Screen.fxml** inside the **ui** folder
2. Load it with the instruction: `FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("../ui/Screen.fxml"));`.